# my output array to merge into just one array

Tags: perl

My sample code to display the lists of directory listed in source_dir_ref.txt but I need to merge it to one array

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;

my $infile = 'source_dir_ref.txt';
my $file = $ARGV[0];

GetOptions ("infile=s" => \$file ) or die("Error in command line arguments\n");

open(DATA, $infile) or die "Couldn't open file $file";

while(my $line = <DATA>) {
         chomp($line);
         #say "$line";
         my @listdir = $line;
         say Dumper \@listdir;

}
```

My result after running my code

```
$VAR1 = [
          '/archives/data/mefab/STAGING/PRODUCTION'
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          '/archives/data/bkfb/STAGING/PRODUCTION'
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          '/archives/data/szast/STAGING/PRODUCTION'
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          '/archives/data/cpast/STAGING/PRODUCTION'
        ];
```

My objective is to merge this array to just one array.

```
@sourcedirs = ('/archives/data/mefab/STAGING/PRODUCTION', '/archives/data/bkfb/STAGING/PRODUCTION', '/archives/data/szast/STAGING/PRODUCTION','/archives/data/cpast/STAGING/PRODUCTION');
```

Comment: Perl usually automerges (flattens) arrays. Did you try that?

Comment: I did not.  i like pass it to this name`@sourcedirs`

Comment: Try by assigning all the arrays to a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is fix this one line.

```
my @listdir = $line;
```

to

```
push @listdir, $line;
```

Then after the loop do `chomp @listdir`.

The easier way is this:

```
@listdir = <DATA>;
chomp @listdir;
```

Thanks.

Comment: u mean this check?

Answer (score 4):

You can create the array outside the loop and [push](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push) (append) new elements to it.

```
my @sourcedirs;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
     chomp($line);
     push @sourcedirs, $line;
}
```

You could also assign the file handle to an array and chomp after reading all lines:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $F, '<', $file or die "Cannot read $file: $!";
my @sorcedirs = <$F>;
close $F;
chomp(@sorcedirs);
print join ", ", @sorcedirs;
```

Or, use [File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp):

```
use File::Slurp;
my @sourcedirs = read_file($file);
```

Comment: A much better answer.  I'd just comment on the use of name `DATA` for a filehandle -- that's used by perl if there is a `__DATA__` section so it is an unfortunate choice.  And it's anyway (way) better to use a lexical filehandle of course, like you do in your own code.   I see that that is from the OP but It's something that I would comment on.